# Spring Boot + Azure - App stops logging after starting up on Azure

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, logback

I'm working on this Spring Boot app using logback and apache commons logging, configured to generate log files within a 'logs' folder. The app works perfectly well on local, however when it's deployed to Azure, the app logs will only go up until the moment the application starts, and after Spring Boot prints the "Started XYZApplication in 36.186 seconds", nothing else shows up.

We tried to add different levels of logs, including INFO and ERROR, and it still doesn't show up in the log file. Next up we've created an endpoint to returned some info in the response:

```
// Log and LogFactory from org.apache.commons.logging
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CacheAdminController.class);


@RequestMapping(value = "/checkLogs", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> checkLogs() {
    LOG.info("This INFO log should show up");
    LOG.error("This ERROR log should show up");
    String response = String.format("Is log error enabled? %s Is log info enabled? %s Is log debug enabled? %s", LOG.isErrorEnabled(), LOG.isInfoEnabled(), LOG.isDebugEnabled())
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

This endpoint returns true for both the isInfoEnabled and isErrorEnabled, but the actual LOG.info and LOG.error won't show up in Azure. It's a really baffling situation. What could be causing this? Why is it enabled but not coming up? And why is it only happening when deployed to Azure? The logback configuration is the exact same for both local and Azure, so I don't think that's it.

I've even set my log levels to TRACE but couldn't find any useful information in there.

If anyone could shed a light, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I've even set my log levels to TRACE but couldn't find any useful information in there.

I have tried using **TRACE** logs in my **Application.Properties**

[image]

Then, I created a **Logback.xml** File. see below!

```
<configuration>  
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>  
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/app.log"/>  

<appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">  
<file>${LOG_FILE}</file>  

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">  
<fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>  
<!-- each archived file, size max 5KB -->  
<maxFileSize>5KB</maxFileSize>  
<!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20KB,  
it will delete old archived file -->  <totalSizeCap>20KB</totalSizeCap>  
<!-- 60 days to keep -->  
<maxHistory>60</maxHistory>  
</rollingPolicy>  
<encoder> <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>  
</encoder> </appender>  
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">  
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">  
<Pattern>  %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n  
</Pattern>  
</layout> </appender>  

<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">  
<smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>  
<smtpPort>587</smtpPort>  
<STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>  
<username>emailid</username>  
<password>password</password>  
<to>emailid</to>  
<from>emailid</from>  
<subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>  

<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>  
</appender>  
<logger name="com.Springbootfirst" level="error" additivity="false">  
<appender-ref ref="EMAIL"/>  
</logger>  
<logger name="com.Springbootfirst" level="trace" additivity="false">  
<appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>  
</logger>  
<root level="error">  
<appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>  
</root>  
<logger name="com.Springbootfirst" level="debug" additivity="false">  
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>  
</logger> <root level="error">  
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>  
</root>  
</configuration>
```

I Started running My application in local, its working fine and started creating logs and then, Deployed in Azure Spring App
[image]
[image]

App is Running fine in Azure also.
[image]

[image]

And Then, Logs also Generated. Check below!
[image]